# iOS Multiple push notifications using php code does not send to all devices

Tags: php, ios, apple-push-notifications

I am using ios push notifications. All certificates are created correctly. Notifications are going using php server code :-

```
$deviceTokens; // This is an array which has all tokens
$passphrase; // This is my passphrase

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'iOSPushNotificationCertificate.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'cafile', 'entrust_2048_ca.cer');
$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

$body; // This is my notification data body

$payload = json_encode($body);

for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($arr); $i++) {

    $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $arr[$i]) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

    $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

    echo $result;

}

fclose($fp);
```

The **echo $result** code is giving me integer values for all good or bad tokens.

When all tokens are good then all devices are getting notifications. But the problem is if one token in between is old or expired or something like that then all notifications after this expired token are not going. The for loop is executing for all tokens but notifications are going for tokens only which are before the bad token. What can be done?

Comment: try to loop through : foreach($deviceToken as $token){
    $msg = chr(0) . pack("n",32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $token)) . pack        ("n",strlen($payload)) . $payload;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many efforts i found what was going wrong. The one token which is old or expired i was talking about in my question is the token generated by development APNs certificates (may be during development the distribution url got called and development token got saved in server), all other tokens are generated from distribution certificates. So if you send one development token in between distribution tokens the apple server shuts the connection with our server, and other tokens which are after that development token do not get processed. Never mix development and distribution tokens. Thank You.